# Filter number with option "begins with"

Tags: vba, filter

Can we filter number in excel with option "begins with", when I filter at the box "search" of combobox ex: 15*. It's ok, but in Number Filters/Custom Filters I use "begins with" it didn't work. I try to record Macro with the way "search" in combobox for the code but it is impossible.

How to write VBA code for this. Thank you, this is the macro recorded.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$8:$AF$1194").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=Array( _  
    "1521", "1522", "1526", "1541", "1542", "1543", "1561"),Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

But I wanna filter the value 15*

Comment: Please show the code you've tried that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct, that is not possible in AutoFilter.
Here's a way though if your data are numbers.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$8:$AF$1194").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=">=1500"
```

Or this if you specifically want those with **15** in it.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$8:$AF$1194").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=">=1500" _
    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<1600"
```

**Edit1:** Answer to follow-up in comment

You can change all your data into *Text* by using *Text To Columns* under **Data Tab**.
**Steps:**

1. Select the entire column where you have your data in number format.
2. Then click on *Text To Columns*. Press *Next* on the 1st and 2nd dialogue box.
3. On the 3rd dialogue box, select *Text* instead of *General*.

Now, all your data are in the form of text.
You can then use below code to filter all that begins with **15**.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$8:$AF$1194").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="15*"
```

Comment: I have thought this way but the number may be more than thousand, I just want to pick the number begins with 15. But begins with just for text, why it doesn't recognize number as text although I format it to text

Comment: @kobebryant If it is ok to change the numbers to text, see my edit.

Comment: Awesome, when I change to text normally the excel program be crashed, but I used VBA it's run smoothly, lol. Thank you so much L42, I don't know how to make friend with you

Comment: @kobebryant We already are friends and with the rest of SO community. They may criticize you or DV and close some of your questions but that is for you to learn. That's real friends for me.

Comment: thank you so much, all what you said is good. First time I join in SO I really love this forum's apperance especially member likes you. All my post perfomed not good, but I'm try to adapt.